# how to log Spring RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, logging, handler, runtimeexception

I'm having trouble logging RuntimeExceptions from my Spring service.

My configuration is:

jars (Maven):

- I have excluded commons-logging
- I have log4j and sl4j on the classpath

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, infrastructure

log4j.appender.infrastructure=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.infrastructure.File=/opt/logs/infrastructure.log
log4j.appender.infrastructure.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infrastructure.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} (%t) %-5p [%c] - %m%n
```

and in a service method:

```
throw new IllegalStateException();
```

I should mention that I'm using Spring MVC. The Spring version is 3.0.5. Tomcat 7.0.11 as a web server.

My goal is to have the IllegalStateException logged as any other normal exception would - to my log appender. I looked for a way to register a global UncaughtExceptionHandler but couldn't find any, so I guess my runtime exceptions aren't being logged. Instead they're being outputted to standard out.

How should I fix this? 
Any help is appreciated.

Eugen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html).

See the Spring MVC Reference on [Handling Exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

Comment: I am aware of the Spring exception resolvers, and will look into them more. But my assumption was that logging the exception is an orthogonal concern and should still look at how I have logging set up regardles of any exception resolvers. Am I to understand from your response that my assumption was wrong? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Something needs to catch the exception and log it otherwise it will go all the way up to Tomcat.